# How to keep two spans still while adding and removing a border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After clicking the span, it will add or remove a dotted border. You can see them moving a little after adding or removing a border. I just want to them keep still.

My code:

```js
    var border_style = "2px dotted RED"
    document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function (node) {
        node.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.style.border != "") {
                e.target.style.border = ""
            } else {
                e.target.style.border = border_style
            }
        })
    })
```

```html
<span id="a">
    span a
</span>

<span id="b">
    span b
</span>
```

So, How to keep two spans still while adding and removing a border?

Comment: you better change the border style to transparent (or similar to background color.).

Comment: here is much shorter code using jquery and css:  http://www.codeply.com/go/QEnA2RN9YV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a transparent border to start.

```js
var border_style = "2px dotted RED"
var non_border_style = "2px dotted transparent"

document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function(node) {
  node.style.border = non_border_style

  node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.style.borderColor !== 'transparent') {
      e.target.style.border = non_border_style
    } else {
      e.target.style.border = border_style
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<span id="a">
    span a
</span>

<span id="b">
    span b
</span>
```

Comment: Made a correction to apply the initial style in JS and fix toggling.

Answer (score 5):

There are (at least) three ways to fix this.

1. Set the default style to `border: 2px solid transparent`.
2. Add negative left and top margins to counteract the movement of the block.
3. Use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include the border in the element size (CSS3).

Comment: box sizing won't work because span element are inline by default.

Comment: @maioman That is true. Consider that rule a more general one.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `border: 2px solid transparent` (css) as a placeholder:

```js
var border_style = "2px dotted RED"
    document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function (node) {
        node.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.style.border != "") {
                e.target.style.border = ""
            } else {
                e.target.style.border = border_style
            }
        })
    })
```

```css
span{
  border: 2px solid transparent
    }
```

```html
<span id="a">
    span a
</span>

<span id="b">
    span b
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fix this way adding a white border or transperant border to span

```js
    var border_style = "2px dotted RED"
    document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function (node) {
        node.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.style.border != "") {
                e.target.style.border = ""
            } else {
                e.target.style.border = border_style
            }
        })
    })
```

```html
<style>
  span { border:2px dotted #fff; }
</style>

<span id="a">
    span a
</span>

<span id="b">
    span b
</span>
```

Comment: Making the border white limits the solution to a white background. Transparent gives you greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the border, just change the border colour same as background colour let say white.

var border_style = "2px dotted RED"

```
var new_border_style = "2px dotted WHITE"

document.querySelectorAll( 'span' ).forEach( function ( node )
{
    node.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e )
    {
        if ( e.target.style.border == border_style )
        {
            e.target.style.border = new_border_style
        } else
        {
            e.target.style.border = border_style
        }
    } )
} );
```